# Angular 2 stomp service consume

Tags: typescript, observable, stomp

I am getting `responseBody` as undefined but I am getting the subscribe   response in msg_body. Whats wrong with `responseBody`?

```
 let stomp_subscription = this._stompService.subscribe('/topic/queue');
stomp_subscription.map((message: Message) => {
  return message.body;
}).subscribe((msg_body: string) => {
  console.log(`Received: ${msg_body}`);
  this.responseBody = JSON.parse(msg_body);
  console.log('RESPONSECODE' + this.responseBody.ResponseInfo.ResponseCode);
});
```

Comment: can you try with my answer below

Answer (score 0):

you are using `return` statement from the `.map()` operator of the Observable. Hence the value is not passed to the next `.subscribe()` call against the Observable. Can you try with the below code

```
    let stomp_subscription = this._stompService.subscribe('/topic/queue');
    stomp_subscription.map((message: Message) => message.body )
     .subscribe((msg_body: string) => {
      console.log(`Received: ${msg_body}`);
      this.responseBody = JSON.parse(msg_body);
      console.log('RESPONSECODE' + this.responseBody.ResponseInfo.ResponseCode);
    });
```